# How to setting elasticsearch firewall rule

Tags: elasticsearch, firewall, outbound, inbound

I heard from elasticsearch site about When I start elasticsearch, I should open port 9200 (inbound rule).

(1) This mean is that My server is destination from something server have data?
(2) Can I open outbound is anywhere?

I need this information because if I want open some port, I need request to My security team with information that source IP,Port / destination IP,Port. So if (1) right, What is source server Ip?
I am beginner with firewall and elasticsearch, so I couldn't understand about this. Please explain this question.